# How do we end up with three vowels at the end of Περικλέους? (Greek)

Tags: etymology, greek, morphology, names

According to Wiktionary, the genitive of [Περικλῆς](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%A0%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%BB%E1%BF%86%CF%82), or Περικλέης, is Περικλέους; and similarly, that of [Σοφοκλῆς](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%A3%CE%BF%CF%86%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%BB%E1%BF%86%CF%82), or Σοφοκλέης, Σοφοκλέους.

Question:  How do we end up with three vowels, εου, at the end of these genitives?  (Or morae if we are going to say ου is *a* vowel.)

**Background**

The last vowel, I venture to guess, comes from -ος, the genitive singular suffix for third declension nouns.  I know that it sometimes combines with a stem ending in a vowel and undergoes a change, as in γένους from γένεος.

But to have three vowels together, we would need a stem ending in two vowels or somehow get an extra vowel in there between stem and suffix.

According to Wiktionary, the etymology of Περικλῆς is:

> περῐ- (peri-, “very”) +‎ κλέος (kléos, “fame”) +‎ -ής

Could it be that between εο (from κλέος) and η (from -ής), we somehow ended up with a stem ending in two vowels?

Relevant too seems the case of of [Σωκράτης](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%A3%CF%89%CE%BA%CF%81%CE%AC%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%82). Its stem is Σωκρατε(s) (according to Mastronarde's Introduction to Attic Greek).  The (not necessarily etymological) operation that takes you from word to stem is: (1) remove -ης, yielding Σωκρατ, and (2) add ε(s), yielding Σωκρατε(s).  The same operation on Περικλέης gives you Περικλεε!  Or at least there is some sort consistency here.

I would note that the question above on the genitive recurs for <strike>the dative and</strike> the accusative as well, e.g. <strike>Περικλεῖ and</strike> Περικλέᾱ, where we get three morae at the end, if not vowels. Compare <strike>ἀσπίδι and</strike>  ἀσπίδα; <strike>Σωκράτει (Σωκράτεϊ) and</strike>  Σωκράτη (Σωκράτεα).  (Note:  I struck Περικλεῖ because it does not have three morae.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These names are compounds of κλέος, earlier κλέϝος (klewos). This is a neuter s-stem, like γένος. So the gen. sing. is *klewesos > *kleweos, regularly contracted to κλέ(ϝ)ους (ε + ο > ου). (Αs it happens, κλέος is attested only in the nom./acc. sing. and plural, but the missing forms can be reconstructed on the basis of other words). The only irregularity is the nom. sing. in -ῆς, which appears to be borrowed from the masc. first-declension nouns, by analogy to the many masc. names of this type.

Comment: A question: do you understand why the accusative is Περικλέᾱ rather than Περικλέη given the historical presence of digamma after the epsilon? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attic_Greek#Long_a) suggests that Proto-Greek *ā was usually raised after digamma, e.g. in Attic korē < korwā, but maybe the situation is more variable than mentioned there

Comment: The nom. sg. isn't necessarily irregular, but could be due to a different vowel grade (e-grade rather than o-grade) -- ablaut in compounds isn't always the same as in the simplex. @sumelic, the uncontracted form of the acc. would be -kle(w)ea, and εα (in Attic anyway) sometimes contracts to η and sometimes to ᾱ -- I don't know what determines the choice.